# Trouble with rails hidden fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a little confused on how hidden form fields work in Rails, like for example I have two hidden fields in my form like so:

*(for a polymorphic model for commenting)*

```
<%= form_for [commentable, commentable.comments.build], :remote => 'true' do |form| %>
  <%= hidden_field "resource", commentable.class.to_s.downcase %>
  <%= hidden_field "resource_id", commentable.id %>

  <%= form.text_area :body %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Post comment' %>
<% end %>
```

But so this works fine and what not, but the params that I receive in my controller are like this:

```
"resource"=>"photos", "resource_id"=>{"174"=>""}
```

Why is my `resource_id` param a hash too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<%= hidden_field "resource_id", commentable.id.keys[0] %>

A better question would be, where and how are you assigning the id?

Comment: hmmm... odd, this seems like the proper solution, I do however receive this error: `undefined method `keys' for 1:Fixnum`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question directly, but... Take out the resource_id and look in your params in the log file, I think the id is already passed in the url because of the path you provide in the form_for call